# how to create bat file on system start or hibernate and sleep

Tags: windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

Recently I finished developing a Java application using JavaFX. Now I want to automatically run the application when the system starts, restarts or hibernates. I'm using the code below.

```
REG ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /v JApp /t REG_SZ /d "%~dp0MoodOMeter.jar"
TIMEOUT /T 100
```

Currently it works only on start and restart, but not on hibernate and sleep. Also, this works only on Windows at the moment. Is there a way to do this on Linux and OS X as well?

Comment: Do you mean you want it to run when the system wakes from sleep/hibernation?

Comment: you can google how to run something when computer wakes from hibernation, many results on that. Or for sleep.     And you can look up how to do it in linux and so on.  When you can do those things, then you could start asking how to do some generic thing that works for both windows and linux, or how  to do it generically that works for start or restart, but really it's unlikely to find something super generic, or super generic and still reasonably simple.

Answer (score 0):

There is no single function that will let you configure this on all OS's.

On Windows, you should look at the `Task Scheduler` which gives you a much more robust set of capabilities for ensuring tasks start when you need them to. It is similar (in some ways) to `systemd` on Linux.

As mentioned, on Linux, you need to install a `systemd` script. Not sure about OSX.

You would get better answers on the ServerFault site rather than here which is targeted at end users rather than system administrators.